# Spring Boot - Hibernate import.sql column names are converted to upper case

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to import default entries into my database with the `import.sql` which gets executed on `ddl-auto: create-drop`.

```
INSERT INTO CAR (vehicleId, manufacturer, model, bodyDesign, capacity, capacityUnit, constructionDate, cylinders, doors, fuelType, gears, gearBox, isElectric, ps, seats, propulsion) VALUES ("WBA5J71050GZ75477", "BMW", "M3", "Coupé", 3246, "m³", PARSEDATETIME('17-03-2015', 'dd-MM-yyyy'), 6, 2, "petrol", 6, "semi-automatic", false, 343, 5, "rear");
```

However the column names i want to insert to are getting converted to upper case automatically:

```
2017-12-11 15:57:04.668 ERROR 24141 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful: INSERT INTO CAR (vehicleId, manufacturer, model, bodyDesign, capacity, capacityUnit, constructionDate, cylinders, doors, fuelType, gears, gearBox, isElectric, ps, seats, propulsion) VALUES ("WBA5J71050GZ75477", "BMW", "M3", "Coupé", 3246, "m³", PARSEDATETIME('17-03-2015', 'dd-MM-yyyy'), 6, 2, "petrol", 6, "semi-automatic", false, 343, 5, "rear")
2017-12-11 15:57:04.668 ERROR 24141 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Column "VEHICLEID" not found; SQL statement:
```

Is there some way to circumvent this issue without renaming all my columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` in application.yml

```
server:
  contextPath:

spring:
  jackson:
    serialization:
      INDENT_OUTPUT: true   
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```